# Erro ao enviar requisição ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estou fazendo um cadastro via ajax, e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:
Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Não realiza o cadastro, segue meus códigos:

```
var dataString = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= BASE; ?>/modulos/index.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: 'action=enviar_ordens&' + dataString,
                    beforeSend: function (data) {
                        $('.msg_error').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Aguarde estamos enviando seu pedido...</div>');
                        $("#btn_order").attr('disabled', true);
                        $('#btn_order').text("AGUARDE UM MOMENTO...").attr({
                            title: "Aguarde... Enviando pedido!"
                        });
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 'success') {
                            $('.msg_error').html('<div class="alert alert-' + data.code + '">' + data.msg + '</div>');
                            $("#btn_order").attr('disabled', false);
                            $('#btn_order').text("Enviar Pedido").attr({
                                title: "Enviar Pedido"
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('.msg_error').html('<div class="alert alert-' + data.code + '">' + data.msg + '</div>');
                            $("#btn_order").attr('disabled', false);
                            $('#btn_order').text("Enviar Pedido").attr({
                                title: "Enviar Pedido"
                            });
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

No meu PHP coloquei isto:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma solução simples para corrigir e como eu faço?

Att,

Alisson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No PHP: `/modulos/index.php` deve mudar de:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

Para:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With');
```

Pois o `X-Requested-With` é um header gerado pelo Ajax do jQuery, e como provavelmente você esta acessando de diferentes domínios este header precisará ser informado.

---

### Adicional não diretamente relacionado a solução do problema com CORS

Vale notar que talvez nem precisaria passar os headers de `Access-Control-*`, pois acredito que seu Ajax e seu PHP estejam no mesmo host, mas talvez você tenha ajustado a constate `BASE` de maneira errada, então se o seu `BASE`:

```
 http://site.com
```

Mas estiver tentando acessar o site via

```
 http://www.site.com
```

Já vai falhar, precisoando configurar os `Access-Control-*`

Se o problema for isto, como `www.` e sem, então seria mais interessante configurar `BASE` para `www.` e impedir que os usuários acessem sem `www.`, usando `.htaccess` para isto, por exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: a minha constante BASE eu coloco sem o www. e está configurado com https://,

Comment: Sumiu os erros, mais agora minha requisição não funciona

Comment: @AlissonMaciel "não funciona" é bastante ambiguo, não concorda? Dá uma olhada no console do navegador e veja se ocorreu algum erro.

Comment: Bom, troquei o header que vc informou no php, removi o crossdomain, removi o cache e mudei o datatype para json, e agora voltou a funcionar, mesmo com a contante do jeito que está. Eu suponho, que o problema foi realmente o header, e como eu modifiquei o codigo jquery, para tentar corrigir, deu problema, mais eu tinha que mudar apenas o header e deixar o codigo como estava, enfim, voltou a funcionar e obrigado pela solução!